# Kendo.Combobox does not show its options even though there generated in html

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datasource, kendo-combobox

I'm populating `Kendo.Combobox` using Ajax:

```
function Edit(e) {

    $.ajax({   
        url: "/TicketReportProperty/PopulateReportProperty",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {'reportId' : @Html.Raw(Model.ReportID)},
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (data != '') {
                $(data.Data).each(function () {
                    console.log(this.PropertyName + " " + this.ReportGroup);
                    $("#ReportPropertyCB").append($("<option></option>").html(this.PropertyName));
                });                   
            }
        }   
  });  
}
```

The combobox is inside of the `EditorTemplate` defined in the `Kendo.Grid()`:

```
co.Bound(c => c.PropertyName).Title("Property Name").EditorTemplateName("_PropertyNameEditor");
```

This is the `Kendo().ComboBox`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("ReportProperty")
    .DataTextField("PropertyName")
    .DataValueField("ReportPropertyID")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ReportPropertyCB" })
)
```

After Ajax's success, I inspected the Html code and options are there:

[image]

However, they are not displayed inside of a combobox.

What am I missing here?

Comment: what's idCB? are you sure that jQuery selector is selecting what you want? Also your if statements are identical.

Comment: Just changed it. Copied it wrong

Comment: looks like your data-bind is set to something and you're setting each option manually, you only need to do one or the other

Comment: I saw that, but not sure how to fix it. The options are there, but not sure how to bind

Comment: Binding data to an input and typing them in manually are two ways to do the same thing. You've done both here so they're probably cancelling each other out. In the input named ReportProperty just highlight the part that says data-bind= and whatever is between the "" and delete it. Then save it, run it and you should see the options that you typed in manually.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining datasource different way:

```
$("#ReportPropertyCB").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.data(data.data);
```

That logic did that